# Get color fill on RaphaelJS element at custom coordinate

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

It's there a way to get the fill color of RaphaelJS element at a screen point(x,y)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Event driven is like `element.click(function() {
        console.log(this.attr('fill'));
    });` but you have to setup event handler for each element. That is most probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than attaching a click handler to every single element, you can just attach a click handler to the SVG element itself and then use RaphaelJS's [getElementByPoint](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.getElementByPoint) helper function to find the first element under the cursor.  You'd do something like this:

```
 jQuery( paper.canvas ).click( function( e )
 {
     var parentOffset = jQuery(this).offset();
     var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
     var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

     console.log("Relative position: %s, %s", relX, relY);
     var el = paper.getElementByPoint( e.pageX, e.pageY );
     if ( el )
     {
         console.log( el );
     }
     else
     {
         console.log( "No hit." );
     }
 } );
```

To see an example of this in action, visit [this page on my dev server](http://voidblossom.com/tests/circleHover.php) and keep an eye on the console output.

One caveat: I seem to recall that you need to translate the screen coordinates into Raphael coordinates using a particular technique, depending on scroll offset -- I don't think my code handles the Y coordinate properly if the window is scrolled vertically.

Happy coding.